# Graph Error on Highchart Spider Web

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts, dashboard

I'm currently working to create a dashboard that contains multiple spider web charts on it. The first chart works just great, but the other two are showing the wrong graph.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klKPD.png)

This is the javascript in chart.php (the first chart)

```
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'line'
},

title: {
    text: 'People Commitment',
    x: -80
},

pane: {
    size: '80%'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: [<?php while ($b = mysqli_fetch_array($selectPN)) { echo '"' . $b['point_name'] . '",';}?> ],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0
},

yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: 0
},

tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
},



series: [{
    name: 'Target Point',
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
},]

});
```

Here is the second chart script:

```
Highcharts.chart('container2', {

chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'line'
},

title: {
    text: 'Product/Process Engineering',
    x: -80
},

pane: {
    size: '80%'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: [<?php while ($b = mysqli_fetch_array($selectPN)) { echo '"' . $b['point_name'] . '",';}?> ],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0
},

yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: 0
},

tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
},



series: [{
    name: 'Target Point',
    data: [11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
},

]

});
```

I don't know what's wrong with this script. If I open each of the chart.php files independently, the chart looks just fine. However, if I put all those three charts on the same page, the graph on the charts looks messy even though they have the exact same value.

Comment: Provide us with some data, or better prepare a working JSFiddle demo where this situation happens, otherwise it will hard to recreate the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/coqagxby/1/ here is the demo

Comment: I meant your data. As you can see, in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/b8a3ymov/ charts display correctly, so I assume it must be something wrong with your data. Check the data of each series.

Comment: Sorry, the code above is still the old one. I tried to put ordinary integer series as data (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)  but still fail to show the right points on charts..

Comment: @d_paul in the jsfiddle everything's alright. But once I put three charts (with the same JS) in single php page, the second and third charts have the wrong point even though the data is the same for all charts.

Comment: As I said before, without an example where this issue is recreated, it will be hard to investigate what is wrong. Did you checked your data? Maybe you change it at some point?